# How can I add gaps between groupBox controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

At the top :

```
private int gap = 0;
```

Then in a button click event :

```
private void btnADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fsd = new FolderSelectDialog();
            fsd.Title = "What to select";
            fsd.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
            if (fsd.ShowDialog(IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                AddGroupBox(Path.GetFileName(fsd.FileName));
            }
        }
```

And the AddGroupBox method :

```
private void AddGroupBox(string Name)
        {
            gap = gap + 83;
            GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
            gb.Location = new Point(3, gap);
            gb.Size = new Size(1311, 100);
            gb.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            gb.Text = Name;
            this.Controls.Add(gb);
        }
```

First time the location on y is 83 next time the location is on y 166 but the new groupBox on 1660 is still some of it touch or inside the first groupBox.

I dont wan't a space between them I want that the borders of the first and the next one will touch each other like one common border at the top ofthe new and the bottom of the first. and the same when adding a new groupBox each time.

Comment: You have `gb.Size = new Size(1311, 100);`, so the height of your GroupBox is 100 pixels.  Either change the height to match your gap of 83, or change the gap to 100?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Right You right , but I want that the first groupBox will be at position 83 on the Y height 100 and only from the second including the second to start make it as you suggested for example 100 and 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many ways to do this...

How about just storing the last GroupBox placed and using its Bounds.Bottom property?  If that variable is null, then place at the initial position of 83.

Something like:

```
private int startingY = 83;
private GroupBox lastGB = null;

private void AddGroupBox(string Name)
{
    GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
    gb.Location = new Point(3, (lastGB==null ? startingY : lastGB.Bounds.Bottom));
    gb.Size = new Size(1311, 100);
    gb.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
    gb.Text = Name;
    this.Controls.Add(gb);

    lastGB = gb;
}
```